# How does the mortality rate of corona-virus compare to regular "flu"?

Tags: risks, epidemiology

How does the mortality rate of coronavirus compare to regular "flu" ? Are there enough statistical data to make a good comparison ? Would it be more accurate to compare it to a specific flu such as "bird flu" ?

Comment: Your question lacks prior research.  As you can see from [this question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/is-the-mortality-rate-of-covid-19-41), calculating the mortality rate during an ongoing epidemic with a new disease isn't a simple matter.

Comment: “Feed a virus, starve a bacterial infection” https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/09/160908130545.htm